# Avoid mutiple dynamic Quotes onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

let's say I have data like this

```
---------------
ID | Data
---------------
1  | ABCDEFG //normal
2  | ABCD'EFG // single quotes only
3  | AB'CDE'FG // mutiple single quotes only
4  | ABCD"EFG // double quotes only
5  | AB"CD"EFG // mutiple double quotes only
6  | ABCD"EFG // double quotes only
7  | ABCD`EFG // backtick only
8  | AB`CD`EFG // mutiple backtick only
9  | AB'C"DE`FG // mixing
10 | A"B'C"D'E`F`G // mutiple mixing
```

how best pratice for avoid error when meet with dynamic quotes like that inside onclick function?

```js
let htm +=`
<button onclick="myFunction('` + val1 + `','` + val2 + `','` + val3 + `',.....etc)"></button>
`;
```

example

```js
let val1 = data[0]; // data from ID 1
onclick="myFunction('` + val1 + `')"; // this will be work fine
```

```js
let val1 = data[1]; // data from ID 2
onclick="myFunction('` + val1 + `')"; // this will be error
```

and etc..

if the data static I can handle it  like

```js
let val1 = data[1]; // data from ID 2
onclick='myFunction("` + val1 + `")'; // this will be work fine
```

this the snippets make you easy to understand

```js
let htm = '';

let val1 = 'ABCDEFG';

// try to change val1 with another val
// ABCDEFG
// ABCD'EFG 
// AB'CDE'FG
// ABCD"EFG
// AB"CD"EFG
// ABCD"EFG
// ABCD`EFG
// AB`CD`EFG
// AB'C"DE`FG
// A"B'C"D'E`F`G


htm +=`
  <button onclick="myFunction('` + val1 + `')">MY BUTTON</button>
`;
$(function(){
  $("#btn1").html(htm);
});

function myFunction(val){
  $("#case1").text(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn1"></div>
<div id="case1">click the button</div>
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? How is it getting to your client-side JS?

Comment: i'm using ajax for get data from db

Comment: [Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)

Comment: @zer00ne so we can't use `inline event handlers`  like my snippets above? or just avoid it?

Comment: @AdityaDees Yeah avoid it at all costs especially if you need multiple tags that need to listen for events. In fact you should really use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation). You can have a single tag bound to an event handler and you'll be able to control every tag within it -- unlimited numbers -- even if they are added in dynamically at anytime.

Answer (score 4):

Simply don't create HTML strings. Instead, [create elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [add event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
// fake "fetch", this is just for the demo
const fetch=async()=>({json:async()=>[{id:1,data:`ABCDEFG`},{id:2,data:`ABCD'EFG`},{id:3,data:`AB'CDE'FG`},{id:4,data:`ABCD"EFG`},{id:5,data:`AB"CD"EFG`},{id:6,data:`ABCD"EFG`},{id:7,data:`ABCD\`EFG`},{id:8,data:`AB\`CD\`EFG`},{id:9,data:`AB'C"DE\`FG`},{id:10,data:`A"B'C"D'E\`F\`G`}]})

const out = document.getElementById("case1")
const buttons = document.getElementById("btn1")

// register a delegated event listener
buttons.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const button = e.target.closest("button[data-value]")
  if (button) {
    out.textContent = button.dataset.value
  }
})

// get your data
fetch("https://example.com")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(results => {
    // now create the buttons
    buttons.append(...results.map(({ id, data }) => {
      const button = document.createElement("button")
      button.type = "button"
      button.append("MY BUTTON")
      button.dataset.value = data // register the value as a data attribute
      return button
    }))    
  })
```

```html
<div id="btn1"></div>
<div id="case1">click the button</div>
```

---

Since you've now tagged this with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), here's an alternative. Same concepts, just less code (if you ignore the ~80KB of jQuery)

```js
const out = $("#out")
const buttons = $("#btn1").on("click", "button[data-value]", function() {
  out.text(this.dataset.value)
})

$.getJSON("https://example.com").done(results => {
  buttons.append(results.map(({ id, data }) => $("<button>", {
    type: "button",
    text: "MY BUTTON",
    "data-value": data
  })))
})
```

Comment: I like the way the dynamic thing with event listener. Like your code

Comment: so you still need to add manual ` \ `  backslah right?

Comment: @AdityaDees no, if the data is in a response from an AJAX request you shouldn't need to do anything. I've only got the `data` array in my answer as an example

Comment: @Phil ok I've done quicktest  your snippet and it's work fine, so in conclusion, we can't use html strings like my snippets above?

Comment: @AdityaDees it's probably possible to keep using HTML strings and doing a bunch of escaping but it's definitely not worth it

Comment: In conclusion you *can use html strings*, obviously, just you need to faff about escaping quotes - adding the data directly *in memory* (not as an html string) removes that issue completely, so you can move on.